# Which trees drop apples?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I start a new survival world in minecraft, I always try to find a tree. But other than wood, I need food, and I know that not all trees drop apples. Which trees *do* drop apples?

Comment: Just make a wheat field. All you need are some seeds, a hoe, some dirt, and water.

Comment: That's one idea

Answer (score 4):

[Apples](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Apple) are most commonly dropped by [Oak Trees](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tree#Oak_tree). (Why do *oak* trees drop *apples*? Because it's Minecraft.) They're also dropped by [Dark Oak Trees](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tree#Dark_oak_tree), but as these only grow in the Roofed Forest biome, you're far more likely to find regular oaks first.

Apples aren't a very good food source though: they're unreliable, and even a lot of them don't keep you fed for long. Easier and more filling than apples is to simply perpetrate some violence on chickens, pigs, sheep, cows, or rabbits and eat the meat raw or cooked in a furnace. In the first day of Minecraft, meat is the simplest, most abundant, and most filling food source.

For vegetarian playthroughs of Minecraft, the easiest early food is bread made from planted wheat: obtain seeds by breaking [tall grass](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tall_Grass), use a hoe to till dirt into farmland beside water, and plant the seeds. (See the [farming tutorial](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Wheat_farming) for more.) You'll have to survive several hungry days before your wheat is ready to harvest though.

If you're lucky enough to start near a village, the *best* early vegetarian food source is harvesting and replanting the villagers' fields for your own benefit.

Comment: For 1st (and few more) day, voilence is required! But for rest days you can go for bread or what i did was make a mushroom stew...reelly fills your hunger but is difficult to handle

Comment: @Mukul No violence required, just patience and being hungry. I've done it, so I know it's possible. :) It should be even easier in 1.11 since it has changes that make hunger grow more slowly.